# При подключении многопоточности перестали задаваться переменные

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, vkontakte-api, бот

Делал бота, после подключил многопоточность

```py
for event in longpoll.listen():
    x = threading.Thread(target=bot, args=(event, ))
    x.start()
    x.join()
```

```py
def bot(event):
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        peer_id = event.obj['peer_id']
        from_id = event.obj['from_id']
        user = UserConnect()
        ...
```

Сначала всё работало, но после подключения потоков перестали задаваться переменные

```py
peer_id = event.obj['peer_id']
from_id = event.obj['from_id']
user = UserConnect()
```

Если проблему с peer_id и from_id можно избежать заменой на event.obj, передавая его в качестве аргумента, то с user оказалась проблема.

```
NameError: name 'user' is not defined
```

Пробовал вырезать код из *bot*, создать новую функцию и её вызывать в самом *bot*, но не помогло.

Comment: Говорю сразу, дело не в if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW

Comment: В таком виде, кстати, от многопоточности толку нет. Вы в основном потоке запускаете другой поток и тут же блокируете основой до тех пор, пока дочерний не закончит работу.

Comment: а, да спасибо. но как поток тогда закрыть?

Comment: в конце функции bot?

Comment: @mineko Зависит от того, зачем Вы вообще параллелите. Если результат функции потока не важен, то можно потоки запускать как обычных демонов и забывать про них. Если результат нужен, то думать какие-то механизмы синхронизации.

Answer (score 0):

Поместив код в функцию для многопоточности, я забыл что переменные станут *локальными* а не *глобальными*.
Надеюсь тема кому-то поможет, не я же один такой глупый......